# Route to controller issues

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently studying laravel and for my small project, and I'm having a small issues now.

I'm trying to handle php input in url i.e http://example.com/?page=post&id=1
I currently have this in my controller for post.blade.php

```
public function post($Request $request) 
{
  $page = $request->input('page');
  $id_rilisan = $request->input('id');
  $post = Rilisan::where('id_rilisan', '=', $id_rilisan)->first();
  if($post = null)
  {
    return view('errors.404');
  }
  return view('html.post')
          ->with('post', $post);
}
```

and this is the controller

```
Route::get('/', 'TestController@index');
Route::get('/{query}', 'TestController@post' );
```

How to process the php input to be routed to controller? I'm very confused right now, I've tried several other method for the Route::get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This route `Route::get('/', 'TestController@index')` directs user to the `index` route. So, if you can't change URL structure and you must use this structure, you should get URL parameters in the `index` route like this:

```
public function index()
{
    $page = request('page');
    $id = request('id');
```

Comment: So I don't need the other Route::get?

Comment: @nothingexceptme if you don't use it, you can remove it. The second route will catch URIs like `/some-string`

Answer (score 0):

You can use it a as parameter on your controller :-) see this answer please: https://laravel.io/forum/07-26-2014-routing-passing-parameters-to-controller

for example query parameter in route would be $query parameter in controller method :-)

So like this:

```
Route::get('/{query}', 'TestController@post' );
//controller function
public function controllerfunc($query){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to use query parameters in url. You can simply use this structure `http://example.com/posts/1`

Then your routes will look like this:

```
Route::get('/posts/{post}', 'PostsController@show');
```

And you will be able to access `Post` model instantly in your show method.
Example:

```
public function show(Post $post) {
    return view('html.post', compact('post'));
}
```

Look how small is your code now.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'd like it to be like that, and the function should get the data from database

Comment: This one is getting from database too. Post model will get everything you need from database.